# AWS Cli in Windows wont upload file to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Windows server 12r2 with python 2.7.10 and the aws cli tool installed.  The following works:

```
aws s3 cp c:\a\a.txt s3://path/
```

I can upload that file without problem. What I want to do is upload a file from a mapped drive to an s3 bucket, so I tried this:

```
aws s3 cp s:\path\file s3://path/
```

and it works.

Now what I want to do and cannot figure out is how to not specify, but let it grab all file(s) so I can schedule this to upload the contents of a directory to my s3 bucket. I tried this:

```
aws s3 cp "s:\path\..\..\" s3://path/ --recursive --include "201512"
```

and I get this error "TOO FEW ARGUMENTS"

Nearest I can guess it's mad I'm not putting a specific file to send up, but I don't want to do that, I want to automate all things.

If someone could please shed some light on what I'm missing I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

In case this is useful for anyone else coming after me: Add some extra spaces between the source and target. I've been beating my head against running this command with every combination of single quotes, double quotes, slashes, etc:

```
aws s3 cp /home/<username>/folder/ s3://<bucketID>/<username>/archive/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.csv"
```

And it would give me: "aws: error: too few arguments" Every. Single. Way. I. Tried.

So finally saw the --debug option in `aws s3 cp help`
so ran it again this way:

```
aws s3 cp /home/<username>/folder/ s3://<bucketID>/<username>/archive/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.csv" --debug
```

And this was the relevant debug line:

```
MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['s3', 'cp', 'home/<username>/folder\xc2\xa0s3://<bucketID>/<username>/archive/', '--recursive', '--exclude', '*', '--include', '*.csv', '--debug']
```

I have no idea where `\xc2\xa0` came from in between source and target, but there it is! Updated the line to add a couple extra spaces and now it runs without errors:

```
aws s3 cp /home/<username>/folder/   s3://<bucketID>/<username>/archive/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.csv"
```

Answer (score 4):

> `aws s3 cp "s:\path\..\..\" s3://path/ --recursive --include "201512"`
>   TOO FEW ARGUMENTS

This is because, in you command, double-quote(`"`) is escaped  with backslash(`\`), so local path(`s:\path\..\..\`) is not parsed correctly.

What you need to do is to escape backslash with double backslashes, i.e. :

`aws s3 cp "s:\\path\\..\\..\\" s3://path/ --recursive --include "201512"`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can try 'mc' which comes as single binary is available for windows both 64bit and 32bit. 'mc' implements mirror, cp, resumable sessions, json parseable output and more - https://github.com/minio/mc

- 64-bit from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/windows-amd64/mc.exe
- 32-bit from https://dl.minio.io/client/mc/release/windows-386/mc.exe

Answer (score 0):

Use `aws s3 sync` instead of `aws s3 cp` to copy the contents of a directory.

Comment: aws s3 sync NetworDriveSource s3://path/ returns too few argument error.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see the error with the information you are giving. I'd have to see your exact command to be able to help.

Comment: P:\>aws s3 sync "s:\folder\folder\DAILY\" s3://folder/
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws.cmd: error: too few arguments

Comment: If I go to the directory first and don't try to pass it in as a source it works. Which is annoying but another topic for another day. if I do 'aws s3 sync . s3://path/ it sends up what I want. Why it took CD to get to the directory for it to work I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation. Let share two scenarios I had tried to check the same code.

1. Within bash
   please make sure you have AWS profile in place (use $aws configure). Also, make sure you use a proper proxy if applicable.

`$aws s3 cp s3://bucket/directory/ /usr/home/folder/ --recursive --region us-east-1 --profile yaaagy`

it worked.

2. Within a perl script

   `$cmd="$aws s3 cp s3://bucket/directory/ /usr/home/folder/ --recursive --region us-east-1 --profile yaaagy"`

I enclosed it within "" and it was successful. Let me know if this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem recently, and [quiver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541952/165494) -- replacing single backslashes with double backslashes -- resolved the problem I was having.

Here's the Powershell code I used to address the problem, using the OP's original example:

```
# Notice how my path string contains a mixture of single- and double-backslashes
$folderPath = "c:\\a\a.txt"
echo "`$folderPath = $($folderPath)"

# Use the "Resolve-Path" cmdlet to generate a consistent path string.
$osFolderPath = (Resolve-Path $folderPath).Path
echo "`$osFolderPath = $($osFolderPath)"

# Escape backslashes in the path string.
$s3TargetPath = ($osFolderPath -replace '\\', "\\")
echo "`$s3TargetPath = $($s3TargetPath)"

# Now pass the escaped string to your AWS CLI command.
echo "AWS Command = aws s3 cp `"s3://path/`" `"$s3TargetPath`""
```