# Errno 22 When downloading multiple files from S3 bucket "sub-folder"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I've been trying to use the AWS CLI to download all files from a sub-folder in AWS however, after the first few files download it fails to download the rest. I believe this is because it adds an extension to the filename and it then sees that as an invalid filepath.

I'm using the following command;

```
aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/sub_folder /tmp/ --recursive
```

It gives me the following error for almost all of the files in the subfolder;

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\tmp\\2019-08-15T16:15:02.tif.deDBF2C2
```

I think this is because of the .deDBF2C2 extension it seems to be adding to the files when downloading though I don't know why it does. The filenames all end with .tif in the actual bucket.

Does anyone know what causes this?

**Update: The command worked once I executed it from a linux machine. Seems to be specific to windows.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535969/aws-cli-in-windows-wont-upload-file-to-s3-bucket

Comment: try this instead of /tmp` which break path `aws s3 cp s3://my_bucket/sub_folder . --recursive`

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: try to run the command from other drive then `C`

Comment: I only have a C drive

Comment: okay, can you try this in `git bash` or another bash environment in the window.

Comment: I've tried git bash and powershell. Same thing on both. I've also tried using sync which gives the same error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an oversight *by AWS* using Windows reserved characters in Log files names! When you execute the command it will create all the directory's however any logs with `::` in the name fail to download.

Issue is discussed here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4543

So frustrated I came up with a workaround by executing a "DryRun" which prints the expected log output and porting that to a text file, eg:

```
>aws s3 cp s3://config-bucket-7XXXXXXXXXXX3 c:\temp --recursive --dryrun > c:\temp\aScriptToDownloadFilesAndReplaceNames.txt
```

The output file is filled with these **aws log entries we can turn into aws script commands**:

> (dryrun) download: s3://config-bucket-7XXXXXXXXXXX3/AWSLogs/7XXXXXXXXXXX3/Config/ap-southeast-2/2019/10/1/ConfigHistory/7XXXXXXXXXXX3_Config_ap-southeast-2_ConfigHistory_AWS::RDS::DBInstance_20191001T103223Z_20191001T103223Z_1.json.gz  **to** \AWSLogs\7XXXXXXXXXXX3\Config\ap-southeast-2\2019\10\1\ConfigHistory\703014955993_Config_ap-southeast-2_ConfigHistory_AWS::RDS::DBInstance_20191001T103223Z_20191001T103223Z_1.json.gz

In Notepad++ or other text editor you replace the `(dryrun) download:` with `aws s3 cp`

[image]

Then you will see the following lines with the command: aws s3 cp, the Bucket file and the local file path. We need to remove the **::** in the local file path on the right side of the **to**:

```
aws s3 cp s3://config-bucket-7XXXXXXXXXXX3/AWSLogs/7XXXXXXXXXXX3/Config/ap-southeast-2/2019/10/1/ConfigHistory/7XXXXXXXXXXX3_Config_ap-southeast-2_ConfigHistory_AWS::RDS::DBInstance_20191001T103223Z_20191001T103223Z_1.json.gz to AWSLogs\7XXXXXXXXXXX3\Config\ap-southeast-2\2019\10\1\ConfigHistory\7XXXXXXXXXXX3_Config_ap-southeast-2_ConfigHistory_AWS::RDS::DBInstance_20191001T103223Z_20191001T103223Z_1.json.gz
```

We can replace the **::** with **-** only in local paths not S3 Bucket path's using  a regex `(.*)::` that removes the last occurrence of chars at the end of each line:

[image]
And here we can see I've replaced the ::'s with hyphens `$1-` by clicking 'Replacing All' twice:

[image]

Next remove the **to** (ignore the | cursor icon in the below image, **to** should be replaced with nothing).
FIND: `json.gz to AWSLogs`
REPLACE: `json.gz AWSLogs`

[image]

Finally select all the lines copy/paste into a command prompt to download all the files with reserved file characters!

**UPDATE:**

If you have WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) you should be able to download the files and then issue a simple file rename replacing the ::'s before copying to the mounted Windows folder system.

Comment: Genious! Thank you for taking the time to share!

Comment: Also, a more modern and faster way to adjust the -dryrun file to prepare for downloading the files is to use ChatGPT. If you ask, he can treat the text in any way necessary, including removing the last occurrence of a char or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I tried from my raspberry pi and it worked. Seems to only be an issue with Windows OS.

Comment: The `:` character is reserved in Windows.

Comment: Filenames with spaces also cause the same issue apparently.