# AWS S3 sync bucket adding a random extension to filename

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to download an entire S3 bucket to my local machine using the
`aws s3 sync s3://mybucketname .`  command.

I get an error like:

```
download failed: s3://bucketname/android/directory_name/filename.csv to android\directory_name\filename.csv [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\prase\\bucketname\\android\\directory_name\\filename.csv.422cd5B1'
```

I know that this error is because of having an extension to the csv extension in the filename. However, I am not sure how this extension is added. All the csv files have an 8-digit extension like **.422cd5B1** and thus download fails. However, when I login to S3 and download each file, there is no extension like this.

All of my files are csv files either uploaded from an android or an ios phone. And only files uploaded from an android phone have this issue.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps it's this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786113/errno-22-when-downloading-multiple-files-from-s3-bucket-sub-folder

Comment: @jspcal thank you for pointing me to the correct direction. It seems that files from ios phones are downloading without error because it doesn't contain any ":" in its filename but the android filenames do and I am using a Windows machine.