# Errno 22 When uploading multiple files to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I have been using the AWS CLI to upload files from a directory to an S3 bucket. After it runs for a while and uploads quite a few files, it will fail to upload some with the Errno 22.

[ErrNo 22 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcC7e.png)

There are no special characters, but from I have been reading online, it's an AWS oversight with Windows characters? I can understand that downloading, but uploading as well?

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated.

```
$LocalFolder = "<backupfolder>" 
$s3Bucket = "<s3folder>" 
$Logfile = "D:\JobOutput\PSLogs\S3Sync" + (Get-Date -f yyyyMMddhhmmss) + ".log" 
$s3 = $s3.Replace($s3.Substring(0,7),"s3://$s3Bucket") 
$s3args = "s3 sync $LocalFolder $s3 --region us-west-2" # > $Logfile 
$cmd = "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\AWS.exe" 
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath $cmd -ArgumentList $s3args -Passthru -Wait
```

I have followed the documentation, and up until about a week ago, I wasn't getting this error, and about a week ago I started getting this error. It has been working for many months, so I'm not sure what changed. It uploads several hundred files BEFORE I get this error, and in looking at the attached screenshot there are no special characters, etc. in the files that is erroring trying to upload.

Comment: Can you share the CLI command here bro?

Comment: It's windows file issue. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786113/errno-22-when-downloading-multiple-files-from-s3-bucket-sub-folder

Comment: Sorry, I mean to add that in the original post. Here it is:       $LocalFolder = "<backupfolder>"
$s3Bucket = "<s3folder>"
$Logfile = "D:\JobOutput\PSLogs\S3Sync" + (Get-Date -f yyyyMMddhhmmss) + ".log" 

$s3 = $s3.Replace($s3.Substring(0,7),"s3://$s3Bucket")
$s3args = "s3 sync $LocalFolder $s3  --region us-west-2" # > $Logfile 

$cmd = "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\AWS.exe"
$proc = Start-Process -FilePath $cmd -ArgumentList $s3args -Passthru -Wait

Comment: Thanks Riz, but this is uploading, not downloading files. Does it still apply?

Comment: Given that it previously worked, I wonder whether a filename is causing the problem? Can you put the `$LocalFolder` and `$s3` arguments in quotes? This would prevent spaces and some characters from confusing the AWS CLI command.